# How can I convert this python loop into vector coding?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I convert this loop code to vector notation? I tried a bunch of things including trying to get a logical_and but it doesn't broadcast.

```
import numpy as np

coord_mask = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=np.bool)
latx = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=10)
laty = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=5)

for i in range(0, coord_mask.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, coord_mask.shape[1]):
        coord_mask[i, j] = latx[i] * laty[j]

print(coord_mask)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to cross an array of length x with one of length y to get a boolean mask array of shape (x, y) where only the xi, yi points will be true, the rest false . Should be so simple but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: `latx[:,None]*laty`

Comment: `range(0, x) == range(x)` for all x > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
In [629]: coord_mask = np.zeros((10, 5), dtype=np.bool)
     ...: latx = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=10)
     ...: laty = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=5)
     ...: 
     ...: for i in range(0, coord_mask.shape[0]):
     ...:     for j in range(0, coord_mask.shape[1]):
     ...:         coord_mask[i, j] = latx[i] * laty[j]
     ...:         
In [630]: coord_mask
Out[630]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Broadcasted multiplication: (the `None` turns `latx` into a (n,1) column matrix, which multliplies a (m,) `laty` (equivalently `(1,m)`), producing a (n,m) result.  This is a very convenient, and powerful `numpy` tool.

```
In [631]: latx[:,None]*laty
Out[631]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`outer`

```
In [632]: np.outer(latx, laty)
Out[632]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

einsum generalization of a dot product:

```
In [633]: np.einsum('i,j',latx, laty)
Out[633]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

With the `broadcasting` approach you can substitute another binary operation like `&`:

```
In [634]: latx[:,None] & laty
Out[634]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers exploring the options. The extension of broadcasting is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that

```
coord_mask = np.outer(latx, laty)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that's the simplest answer in this case.

Comment: Thank you @BishS. However, the solution proposed by @hpaulj (latx[:,None]*laty) that increases dimensionality of one of the arrays (see `newaxis` in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and then uses broadcast multiplication is also elegant and powerful.